# How to pass json result from controller to view in mvc

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have developed a web application using mvc4.i need to pass some `<IList>` from controller to view as **json** result.

below is the code in controller class

```
public ActionResult GetTradeUserData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int test) 
        {
            wholeSaleModelUser = new WholeSaleInfoService().PopulateWholeSaleUserData(test);
            return Json(wholeSaleModelUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and here is the code of view class

```
<script>
$("#submitMarketUser").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "WholeSaleTrade/GetTradeUserData",
        data: { test: $("#Names").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data.EmpNm);

            $("#Contact").val(data.Contact);
            $("#EPFNo").val(data.EPFNo);
            $("#TitlKy").val(data.TitlKy);
            $("#EmpNm").val(data.EmpNm);
            $("#NameInInitials").val(data.NameInInitials);
            $("#DtBirth").val(dateFromStringWithTime(data.DtBirth));
        },
        error: function (e) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

my problem is **data** object not getting any data and alert popup with a text as "undefined".

can somebody please help me here.

Comment: Is the method GetTradeUserData marked with the [HttpPost] attribute? The method won't be hit otherwise as it will default to accepting GET requests and you're POSTing.

Furthermore, did you add a breakpoint and see if your code was actually hit?

Comment: What does `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` show in your success callback?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @steinar yes of course.. 

`return Json(wholeSaleModelUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

in here wholeSaleModelUser get the values as code hit

Comment: @Andrei google chrome

Comment: @DarinDimitrov yes it gives the all values of the properties of **data** object.
but how can i get the individual values for properties of data object like data.Name, data.id, data.address

Comment: Please show the output of it. I need to see the exact JSON returned by your controller action.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov here is the link for screen shot
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v8j22b&s=5

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17292365/29407

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thank you sir.. i got the answer from you.. and please refer the comment in your answer for my last question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, now that you have at last shown the JSON sent by your service it is clear what the problem is. You've got a collection of users and not a single element:

```
[{"Name":"MarketFarmer","Contact":777369369,"Email":"mf@htnsys.com","Fax":114652652,"Address":"kalubowila road,dehivala"}]
```

Also please not that the valid properties of this object are `Name`, `Contact`, `Email`, `Fax` and `Address` but in your code you are attempting to read some `EPFNo`, `TitlKy`, `EmpNo`, `NameInInitials` and `DtBirth` which do not exist in your returned object

So in order to access its values you need to get the element inside the array and then you can access the available properties:

```
success: function (data) {
    var employee = data[0];

    alert(employee.Name);
    alert(employee.Contact);
    alert(employee.Email);
},
```

Comment: Thanx alot sir.! finally i solved the problem with your answer.

Comment: By the way my final step is i need to assign those values to textboxes which exist in a different view(not in the view this script running) one by one.how to do that?how to pass those values to a partial view or another view???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should change ActionResult to JsonResult in your controller

```
public JsonResult GetTradeUserData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int test) 
        {
            wholeSaleModelUser = new WholeSaleInfoService().PopulateWholeSaleUserData(test);
            return this.Json(wholeSaleModelUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: i did the change but i couldn't get a positive answer.problem is still there.

Comment: Have you test if your wholeSaleModelUser variable is not null? Did you add a breakpoint in your controller method?

Comment: yes i checked with a breakpoint and wholeSaleModelUser variable getting approprate result but wont get them in view class